# How to render the depth buffer to texture in pyglet for shadow mapping?

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I want to implement shadowmapping in python using pyglet.
It already works, but just if my window has dimensions of powers of 2.
I want two things to change:

> 1. Render the depth buffer with another resolution than 2^x, 2^y
> 2. Render the depth buffer with a higher resolution than the window.

The Problem with 1. is, that when I change the resolution to something odd and use

```
buffers = get_buffer_manager()
self.depth_tex = buffers.get_depth_buffer().get_texture()
```

I get an error: *pyglet.image.ImageException: Depth texture requires that buffer dimensions be powers of 2*

The Problem #2 is that only the size of the window is written to the depth buffer, the rest is 1. So if my window has the size 512x512 and I set the viewport for the z-buffer to 1024x1024, the z-buffer has a 1024x1024 rectangle with a part of the picture in it, the rest is white.

Code:

```
class MyWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(JuliaWindow, self).__init__(caption = 'julia', width=512, height=512)

    ....

    def on_draw(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        # if no depth texture exists (mesh is static)
        if not self.depth_tex:
            #try it, it won't work (white buffer)
            #glViewport(0,0,1024,1024)
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
            glLoadIdentity()
            gluPerspective(60,self.width/float(self.height),0.5,20)

            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
            glLoadIdentity()
            gluLookAt(2.0,1.5,2.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0)

            glColorMask(GL_FALSE,GL_FALSE,GL_FALSE,GL_FALSE)

            mv = (GLfloat * 16)()
            glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mv)
            p = (GLfloat * 16)()
            glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, p)

            self.shaderD.bind()
            self.batch.draw()

            self.shaderD.unbind()

            buffers = get_buffer_manager()
            self.depth_tex = buffers.get_depth_buffer().get_texture()

        glBindTexture(self.depth_tex.target, self.depth_tex.id)

        #reset viewport
        #glViewport(0,0,self.width,self.height)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluPerspective(60,self.width/float(self.height),0.5,20)

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluLookAt(self.x, self.y, self.z,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0)

        self.shader.bind()
        self.shader.uniform_matrixf('depthMV', list(a))
        self.shader.uniform_matrixf('depthP', list(b))

        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glColorMask(GL_TRUE,GL_TRUE,GL_TRUE,GL_TRUE)

        self.batch.draw()
        self.shader.unbind()
```